# correcting the return type of the method

Tags: java

I have the below code as shown below of which I want to correct the return type

```
  public boolean deleteById(Integer id) throws ResourceNotFoundException {

        abcRepository.deleteById(id);
        return true;
    }
```

what I am looking to correct it as

```
if (abcRepository.deleteById(id))
       {
        return true;
       } else 
        return false;
```

Now this repository is calling the Jpa repository method of which return type in decompiler I have check is shown below

```
void deleteById(ID var1);
```

Now please advise how smartly I can change the return type

Comment: You cannot magically make someone else's code return a value.

Comment: If you need it to return a boolean, you will have to do a findById, assert its existence, deleteById, assert its non-existence, and return a result based on that. But otherwise it is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

Seems you want your method to return `true` when an object is deleted, and false when object is not found.

The method you are calling is `void` because is uses exception `ResourceNotFoundException` to indicate object not found, so you need to catch that exception and return false, instead of making the exception bubble up:

```
public boolean deleteById(Integer id) { // <-- removed throws
    try {
        abcRepository.deleteById(id);
        return true;
    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException ignored) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andread Thanks you got my point finally but how in Java 8 style we can represent the same

Comment: @sdsdsdsdfdfdfwwq that is the "Java 8 way."

Comment: @sdsdsdsdfdfdfwwq In what way is that not "Java 8 style"? If you're thinking *streams* or *lambdas*, then that is not applicable here.